# closeExpiredconnections, closeablehttpresponse.close which one to use and when

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

how do I ensure in my app that httpclient-4.5.5.jar is not throwing socket exception , or stale connections are evicted.

When to call closeExpiredconnections , after how long.

getValidateAfterInactivity is default 2 sec and how to check the optimum value for my app

when close method should not be called on closeablehttpclient and httpresponse

Comment: I can use any number from 1 to 2000 in setValidateAfterInactivity , what factors to check for while setting one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using 
 myConnectionManager.closeExpiredConnections();

before 
        myHttpClient.execute(myTarget, getReq);

along with 
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.

I did not require to setValidateAfterInactivity then.

This worked for me.

close method called on closeablehttpclient and httpresponse defeats the purpose of pooling connections.